# Functions relation to data: Many in, one out: why?

Tags: function, arguments, return-value

I have a question that I cannot answer myself, but it seems like a fundamentally good question to clear up:

Why do some languages restrict the data returned from a function to a single item?

Is this serving some benefit? Or is it a practice brought over from Maths?

An example being (in Scala):

```
def login(username: String, password: String): User
```

If I wanted to return multiple items I cannot say it in the same manner as I just did for the input arguments (now entering imaginary Scala land)

```
def login(username: String, password: String): (User, Context, String)
```

Or even with named data returned:

```
def login(username: String, password: String): (user: User, context: Context, serverMessage: String)
```

Comment: Could you give an example? Also, mathematics has no rules against this. Set notation returns an arbitrary number of items.

Comment: This question boils down to: why do some programming language not have syntactic sugar for handling tuples?

Comment: @Blender: set notation "returns" a single object, the set. The whole idea of set theory is substituting a single object for a collection of them.

Comment: @larsmans: I'm not exactly sure what I was thinking when I commented (facepalm).

Comment: @larmans that's a nice clean way of putting it :) From what I see here, there is no fundamental mathematical concept preventing multiple items returned, it just depends on implementation and what you call that collection eg set, map, list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship: as observed, an arbitrary number of values can be returned, even if they must be "packaged" into a single value.

Imagine a language that can *only* accept a single tuple and can only return a single tuple from a function (the tuples can be any size). These functions then resemble math function transforming a vector from one space to another.

However, some reasons why it might be so:

1. Most functions only return one value, which may be a collection of values (object, sequence, etc.) Decompositions of the single value is supported in a number of languages, even though "only one value is returned".
2. The calling conventions and signatures are simpler: there is no special case/overhead to signal that n-values are being returned: there is no need to use part of the stack to return multiple values, a single register will do.
3. The need to fit in with the target architecture: earlier, especially lower-level languages, were heavily influenced by the computer architecture. In the case of Scala, for instance, it must work on the JVM.
4. It's just how the language was designed. Many (most?) languages borrow heavily -- syntax and/or methodologies -- from existing languages. Sometimes this is good, sometimes it is not so good. C# appeased Java appeased C++ appeased C, for instance: it's all about the market share.
5. It Just Works.

---

Even while "returning only one value", programming languages already have different ways of dealing with it. As noted in the post, some languages allow decomposition (the tuple returned as "decomposed" into it's two values during an assignment):

```
def multiMath (i):
  return (i + i, i * i)

double, squared = multiMath(4)
# doubled is 8
# squared is 16
```

Additionally, other languages like C# which lacks decomposition, allow pass-by-reference (or emulate it in with mutation of an object):

```
void multiMath (int a, out int doubled, out int squared) {
  doubled = a + a;
  squared = a * a;
}

int d, s;
multiMath(4, out d, out s);
// d is now 8
// s is now 16
```

And, of course... ;-)

```
class ANewClassForThisFunctionsReturn {
  ...
}
```

There are likely more methods I am not aware of.

Happy coding.

Comment: "The calling conventions and signatures are simpler" I think that's the original reason. "languages borrow heavily from existing languages" and that's why it's still so common. The rest of the reasons are just perks : )

Answer (score 0):

Because tipicaly returned data is assigned to a variable. And thy are only few languages that can assign two variables in a single sentence.

```
A = sum(1,2)
B,C = dateTime()
```

Technically they are no problem to return more than one parameter because parameters are stacked, the issue is on assignment. Here a sample of this needed:

```
/* div example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  div_t divresult;
  divresult = div (38,5);
  printf ("38 div 5 => %d, remainder %d.\n", divresult.quot, divresult.rem);
  return 0;
}
```

V.S

```
long quot, rem;
quot, rem = div(38,5)
```

Comment: In Scheme, function can return [multiple values](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-rationale/r6rs-rationale-Z-H-13.html#node_sec_11.9.3), but there's no multi-assignment construct, just a multi-binding form. I believe the situation is similar in Common Lisp.

Comment: @larsman, thanks about your appoiment, I like this sentence "However, values in programs usually represent conceptual wholes; in many cases, multiple results yielded by a computation lack this coherence."